# Pre populate dynamic form field

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

The documentation explains [how to dynamically modify forms using form events](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#cookbook-form-events-submitted-data), and especially the POST_SUBMIT event.

Following this example, in a POST_SUBMIT event listener, I can't add a field with pre-populated data like : `$form->add('position', 'text', array('data' => 'It works'));`

The field is added but is empty.

Any idea how can I do this ?

---

EDIT

Basically the form type would look like this :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{

    $builder->add('colors', 'choice', array(
        'choices' => array('blue', 'green', 'red'),
        'multiple' => true,
        'expanded' => true,
        'mapped' => false,
    ));

    $builder->get('colors')->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
        // ... Some logic to determine data to pre populate $myValue
        $myValue = 'It works';

        $form = $event->getForm()->getParent();
        $form->add('position', 'text', array(
            'data' => $myValue
        ));
    });

}
```

Comment: Can you add a little bit more information? Like the event listener class or the form type if the first one doesn't exist.

Comment: My guess would be that the form is trying to populate the field with the submitted data, which it does not have.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, submitted data replaced the default value.
So, in my PRE_SUBMIT listener, I checked if the data were submitted, if not I insert them:

```
public function onPreSubmit(FormEvent $event)
{
    $form = $event->getForm();
    $data = $event->getData();
    if(!isset($data['MY_FIELD'])) {
        $data['MY_FIELD'] = $myCustomData;
        $event->setData($data);
    }
}
```

In my case 'MY_FIELD' was an embed form for an entity and $myCustomData was my entity with it's field set.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the field displays empty when you load it, or the field does not post the $myValue data?  The form will not run the post_submit event listener until the form is submitted so it will apprear blank when you render it.  It will still not show the $myValue data after you submit the form because the controller will redirect or load a different page.
I do not think you need to use an event listener if you only want to show data initially when the form is loaded.  You can set a form value directly in your controller after you created the form but prior to rendering the form.

```
$form->get('position')->setData($myValue);
```

Or perhaps you did want to use an event listeners there you might want to use PRE_SET_DATA instead.  The cookbook link you mentioned has several examples and I think you may want to revisit that code.